# Nginx setup with blazor docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, blazor-server-side

I have created a default blazor server app I now want to deploy via docker container.

My current setup:

- a server configured with Nginx as follows (I followed instructions to install [Nginx](https://www.digital1ocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-debian-11) and [ssl](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-debian-11))

  ```
  server {
    root /var/www/mydomain/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name mydomain.net app.mydomain.net;

    location / {
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass                          http://172.18.0.23:443/;
            proxy_set_header Host               $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.mydomain.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.mydomain.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    }

  server {    
        if ($host = app.mydomain.net) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name mydomain.net app.mydomain.net;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
  }
  ```

I then installed docker on my server, uploaded the container and did some additional setup to make sure my container has correct IP according to my Nginx config file:

```
sudo docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 mysubnet
```

Then I run my container as follows:

```
sudo docker run --hostname=ef93afb9ef97 --env=ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443 --env=DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1 --env=ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS=true --env=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development --env=PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin --env=DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true --env=DOTNET_VERSION=7.0.4 --env=ASPNET_VERSION=7.0.4 --workdir=/app --net mysubnet --ip 172.18.0.23 --restart=no  --runtime=runc -t -d blazortestapp:dev
```

Note I removed port 80 because this was causing an error (default run command generated from VS suggests to us it as follows):

```
--env=ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
```

Now, when I ping my ip 127.8.0.23 I get an answer. But when I try to access my sample application, I get a

> 502 Bad Gateway

What is the catch here? Is it the Nginx config file, the docker run command or both?

**UPDATE **
I removed the docker `subnet` part and attached the ports as follows:

```
sudo docker run [...] -p 8080:80 -p 8081:443 [...]
```

I also made sure to set address to

```
proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8081/;
```

and I still get a bad gateway error...

Answer (score 0):

Don't try use permanent IP with containers!!!
Run you container with  `-p <host_port>:<application_port>`. You host will listen <host_port> and send all request to this port into container app that uses <application_port>. Then change nginx config to

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:<host port from docker run>/;
```

Nginx will send request to localhost with port that is being used to sent request into container.

Or you can use docker-compose and set two service: your app and nginx. Both in containers. And they can communicate each ather by service name without IP.

Comment: I am still fighting with this. I event removed the SSL redirection to try to get things to work but I keep running into "502 Bad gateway" when redirecting `nginx` port 80 to localhost port `8080` which is the one exposed by docker container... Why would that be?

Comment: @neggenbe Is Nginx in conatiner or host installation?

Comment: it is on the host

Comment: @neggenbe Try to connect to your app from your host http://127.0.0.1:<host port from docker run>. If Ok check nginx log, else check container+port

Comment: ok thanks will do that - seems I have an infinite loop somewhere in fact, because I am using a page redirection when first entering the page...!